# how to access items in RecyclerView in fragment from an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have an activity that has a `TabLayout`(where my `Fragments` are in)
and myFragment has a `RecyclerView` itself.
I want to show every touched Item's name in a `textView` in myActicvity.

This is an image that explains my problem.

[image]

How should I do that? Thanks for any Help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Event bus: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. This library help you to send events from one activity/fragment/view to another. You must just add onclicklistener for item root element, and do something like this: `EventBus.getDefault().post(getItemName());`. And at your activty add this:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(String name) {
   textView.setText(name);
};
```

And don't forget to register and unregister listener.

Answer (score 0):

you should write onItemCLickListener in your recyclerView adapter , and then call it from your activity to set textview text.

**Adapter Code:**

```
 OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
 public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }


  public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onClick(int position,String itemName);
    }

 @Override
 public void onBindItemViewHolder(final AdapterRecycelerView.ViewHolderRecyclerItem holder, final int position) {

        try {

            holder.linearItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (onItemClickListener != null)
                        onItemClickListener.onClick(position,arrayList.get(position).getName());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**Activity Code:**

```
 adapterRecycelerView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterRecycelerView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(int position,String itemName) {
                   textview.setText(itemName);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I have adapter as you offered,But the problem is myFragment includes recyclerview not activity,and I want to handle it in my activity

Comment: @Tara: You need to add another listener in fragment to Activity to inform about the click.

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך could you please explain more about it,tnx